# Call method whenever form field is typed in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form which includes a dropdown. A user can either select an option from that dropdown which in turn fills the form field in question, or the user can type their choice manually into the form field.
I want to make sure my dropdown resets upon the user typing in the form field. I'm thinking about some sort of click handler, but know `ng-click` is not appropriate here.

```
<form class="form-inline" name="tagForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <isteven-multi-select
      input-model="header.tagNames"
      output-model="tagsOutput"
      button-label="name"
      item-label="name"
      tick-property="ticked"
      selection-mode="single"
      on-item-click="header.selectTag(data)">
    </isteven-multi-select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="tag" placeholder="Tag" ng-model="header.newTag.tag" ng-required="true">
  </div>
```

So for example, a user selects 'passed' from the dropdown, then rethinks their decision and clicks in the form field to delete 'passed' and type in 'failing'. As soon as the user begins typing (or clicks delete, really any keystroke) the dropdown should reset so no field is selected. How would I call a method from within the form field whenever a keystroke occurs in this field?

Comment: `ng-change` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: @Ronnie, thanks. While that works it appears to be overkill as the method is re-called every time it detects a keystroke. Know of anyway to call it just on that initial keystroke?

Comment: There isn't really a way to limit the number of keystrokes that the model change handler gets called on. The only way to limit that is to perform some validation in the controller to ensure that the handler doesn't execute your code under certain conditions. See this example: http://codepen.io/JacobHeater/pen/aOeVrW?editors=101